# How do I summarize rows in an SQL table?

Tags: sql, sum, rows

I have a table like:

```
EMP_NAME HOURS_WORKED
-------- ------------
Jane               10
Jane                2
Jane               18
Jane               12
Alex                7
Alex                3
Alex                5
Danny              20
Danny              16
```

And I want to condense it into:

```
EMP_NAME TOTAL_HOURS_WORKED
-------- ------------------
Jane                     42
Alex                     15
Danny                    36
```

I tried this, but it didn't run:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT EMP_NAME,
  SUM(HOURS_WORKED) TOTAL_HOURS_WORKED
  FROM EMPLOYEES
;
```

As far as I can tell, you can combine columns with `+`, and you can summarize *all* rows into *one cell* using `SUM()`, but I don't know how to combine rows like this.

I've done my best Google-Fu, but I still can't find anything to help me :/

---

> Please note that this is an example table I made on the spot. I'd never use a name as a primary key ;)

Comment: Any particular dialect of sql? You have not used name as the PK in this instance. In fact, you have no PK, which is a problem! However, a name would be a fine PK as long as you were happy that it was unique and could not change (or you knew how to manage it if it did!)

Comment: @Strawberry Oracle, but I'd like a generic answer if possible

Comment: What is the type of `HOURS_WORKED`?

Comment: @RagingBull it's just an int

Comment: Raging Bull's answer below is probably correct.  Distinct and Sum can sometimes disagree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT EMP_NAME,
SUM(HOURS_WORKED) TOTAL_HOURS_WORKED
FROM EMPLOYEES
GROUP BY EMP_NAME
```

Comment: Agreed. In general, when using aggregate functions with Oracle you are better off using GROUP BY (aggregation) over DISTINCT (analytics). Plenty of discussion on this topic over at [AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com).